# Problem in getting the Latitude and Longitude value using gps at different location

Tags: android, gps

I used the following code to find the longitude and latitude for my android application

```
public double[] getlocation() {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

    Location l = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < providers.size(); i++) {
        l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
        if (l != null)
            break;
    }
    double[] gps = new double[2];

    if (l != null) {
        gps[0] = l.getLatitude();
        gps[1] = l.getLongitude();
    }

    return gps;
}
```

I got the accurate or exact latitude and longitude first time when i run the application after i tried to get the new co-ordinates from one miles away from my first location but i got the same latitude and longitude.

so please can you suggest me how this problem occurs. what is the solution for this ?

Comment: please place the lm.getProvider() method code here. or write the requestUpdateLocation() method code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.getLastKnownLocation() will be inaccurate. You need to use a LocationListener to get accurate and up to date location updates. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) link. You generally ONLY want to use getLastKnownLocation ONCE upon starting to get a quick fix, then register a LocationListener to get more accurate, constant updates.

Also be aware that sitting in your house attempting to test will not work very well. You might need to go outside and walk around some.